# MagicalRecord NSFetchesResultsController section grouping and sorting + within section as well

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, magicalrecord

I'm using `MagicalRecord` to create an `NSFetchedResultsController` for a table.

I've got `NSManagedObjects` that contain groups of people, here are two examples:

```
ContactGroup *everyoneContactGroup = [ContactGroup findFirstByAttribute:@"groupId" withValue:@"<GROUPID>"];
if (!everyoneContactGroup) {
    everyoneContactGroup = [ContactGroup createEntity];
    [everyoneContactGroup setGroupId:@"<GROUPID>"];
    [everyoneContactGroup setGroupName:@"Everyone"];
    [everyoneContactGroup setGroupSortOrder:@1]; // sort order within section
    [everyoneContactGroup setGroupType:@1];
    [everyoneContactGroup setGroupTypeName:@"Smart Groups"];
    [everyoneContactGroup setGroupTypeSortOrder:@0]; // sort order for groups
}

ContactGroup *closeFriendsContactGroup = [ContactGroup findFirstByAttribute:@"groupId" withValue:@"<GROUPIDCLOSEFRIENDS>"];
if (!closeFriendsContactGroup) {
    closeFriendsContactGroup = [ContactGroup createEntity];
    [closeFriendsContactGroup setGroupId:@"<GROUPIDCLOSEFRIENDS>"];
    [closeFriendsContactGroup setGroupName:@"Close Friends"];
    [closeFriendsContactGroup setGroupSortOrder:@2];
    [closeFriendsContactGroup setGroupType:@2];
    [closeFriendsContactGroup setGroupTypeName:@"Custom Groups"];
    [closeFriendsContactGroup setGroupTypeSortOrder:@10];
}

ContactGroup *familyContactGroup = [ContactGroup findFirstByAttribute:@"groupId" withValue:@"<GROUPIDFAMILY>"];
if (!familyContactGroup) {
    familyContactGroup = [ContactGroup createEntity];
    [familyContactGroup setGroupId:@"<GROUPIDFAMILY>"];
    [familyContactGroup setGroupName:@"Family"];
    [familyContactGroup setGroupSortOrder:@1];
    [familyContactGroup setGroupType:@2];
    [familyContactGroup setGroupTypeName:@"Custom Groups"];
    [familyContactGroup setGroupTypeSortOrder:@10];
}
```

The above should show up as follows:

[image]

As you can see, the contact group "Everyone" should be grouped into a section of its own and should appear as the first group in the order of the groups.

The second and third contact group above should be grouped into a section together and this section should appear below the other section with one group in it. Inside this group ("Custom Groups") each contact group should be sorted by their `groupSortOrder`.

Here's my NSFetchedResultsController code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!fetchedResultsController) {
        fetchedResultsController = [ContactGroup fetchAllSortedBy:@"groupTypeSortOrder,groupSortOrder"
                                                           ascending:YES
                                                       withPredicate:nil
                                                             groupBy:@"groupTypeName"
                                                            delegate:self];
    }
    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

I have tried various combinations but cannot get the sort order both for each table view section (group of contact groups) and within each table view section. I know you can add comma-delimited sort attributes, but I just cannot get the combination right. Anyone know if it's possible to achieve what I want with MagicalRecord or do I have to roll some non-MR code .

Thanks in advance for any input and help!

**UPDATE:**

Here's the SQL being generated by Core Data:

```
CoreData: sql: 
SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZGROUPID,  t0.ZGROUPNAME, t0.ZGROUPSORTORDER, 
t0.ZGROUPTYPE, t0.ZGROUPTYPENAME, t0.ZGROUPTYPESORTORDER 
FROM ZTCONTACTGROUP t0 
ORDER BY t0.ZGROUPTYPESORTORDER, t0.ZGROUPSORTORDER
```

**UPDATE:**

So I have tried with grouping by `groupTypeSortOrder` and it works correctly now. However, not I cannot get the section name to appear correctly as it will appear with the numbers for `groupTypeSortOrder` instead. Any ideas?

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!fetchedResultsController) {
        fetchedResultsController = [ContactGroup fetchAllSortedBy:@"groupTypeSortOrder,groupSortOrder"
                                                           ascending:YES
                                                       withPredicate:nil
                                                             groupBy:@"groupTypeSortOrder"
                                                            delegate:self];
    }
    return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the SQL being generated by core data?

Comment: Yeah, can't admit to being super versed SQL person. But I'll add it above.

Comment: @KyleLeNeau Added, see above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with MagicalRecord yet, but I assume that the `groupBy:` parameter corresponds to the `sectionNameKeyPath:` parameter of `NSFetchedResultsController`.

If a key is specified as `sectionNameKeyPath`, then the fetch request must have a first sort descriptor using the same key (or a key generating the same relative ordering).

Therefore, using *groupTypeSortOrder* as first sort key and as `groupBy:` parameter is the correct way.

Now, to display the group names instead of numbers as section headers, you can modify the `titleForHeaderInSection` method, which normally looks like this:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.controller sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];
}
```

But `[sectionInfo name]` is the value of the *groupTypeSortOrder*, because that has been specified as `sectionNameKeyPath` (or `groupBy`). If you modify the method like this:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section { 
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.controller sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [[[sectionInfo objects] objectAtIndex:0] groupName];
}
```

the *groupName* attribute is displayed as section header instead.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing this as well, after realizing it was probably the only way, I just wish / assumed it would have done it automatically :)